# Javascript object in Array Variable is Zero

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created an Array. I then add an object to this array. I later try to access a value from an object inside the array, but it returns 0. What is the issue here?

CODE:

```
var value;
var list = [];


// CALLED FIRST:
function setup() {
    document.onmousemove = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        value = e.pageX;
    }
}

// CALLED SOMETIMES AFTER UPDATE:
function logInfo() {
    var j = 0;
    while (j < list.length) {
        console.log(list[j].value); 
        j++;    
    }
}

// CALLED EVERY 10 MS:
function update(dt) {
    var object = {
        value : value; 
    };
    list.push(input);
}
```

Comment: Is var objects= [] global?

Comment: could you edit the post to add all relevant code ? Your while loop never end, and we don't know how the functions are called, can't reproduce with this code.

Comment: I think the order you declare the array is not in correct. That means you should declare the array before all these methods and keep it global. All the best.

Comment: I edited the code to make it more generalized. Forgot to put ++i. Updated question. Also the array is defined at the top of the js file. So it is global.

Comment: I tried it in the my demo its working fine. can you provide the whole code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that you saved the referance valueNew, which is a number. If you update this reference, it won't update the object.value. You'll need to save the reference for the object itself, and update the value property of that, which will update the object itself. References for numbers/strings are not connected after assignment.

It's not clear for me what this is used for and how exactly, so the code is just an example:

```
var objects= [];
var valueNew = 0;
// Object reference for the the eventListener to access.
// It's here just for the sake of demonstration.
var object = {
    value : valueNew
};

function update() {
    console.log(object.value); // LOGS CORRECT VALUE
    objects.push(object);
};
// I just ran it once.
update();

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Updating the property of the referred object.
    object.value = e.pageX;
    console.log(objects[0].value);
}

// otherFunction was not in scope for the problem.
```

If you'd want to add objects dynamically with the current e.pageX, you could do something like this:

```
var objects= [];
var currentValue = 0;

function update() {

    var object = {
        value : currentValue
    };
    console.log(object.value); // LOGS CORRECT VALUE
    objects.push(object);
};

document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    currentValue = e.pageX;
}

// Calling update will read currentValue,
// and push an object with the currentValue as object.value
update();
```

Comment: What do you mean other function was not in scope? DO you mean it was not part of the issue?

Comment: OP create `object` in `update` scope, there is no reference, `valueNew` is a number.

Comment: Your answer makes no sense .. You add the same object every time in `objects` (reference).

Comment: @Hacketo No, I ment number, I'll update answere, thank you!. The problem is that valueNew is a number, and so not connected to the object you push into the array.

Comment: @TastyLemons It's not part of the issue. It's just reading the objects[], but the problem is that valueNew is just a number. You'll have to save a reference to update the propery of.

Comment: The second answer is exactly what I was doing. But the value is 0.

Comment: @TastyLemons This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rangeoshun/qL3mo7mL/
I just set body.onclick to call update, and otherFunction, to see what's going on. I do not see the issue here, or I missunderstand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @TastyLemons Still running perfectly :) http://jsfiddle.net/rangeoshun/qL3mo7mL/ Had to correct mistakes (object/list name issue, ";" after object property definition). Then I set an interval to update and log in every second after setup().